# How to fit several Layout histograms (12x12)? (python)

Tags: python, dataframe, curve-fitting

I want to do Gaussian fitting on the Layout histogram(12x12).

```
Variable name : pivoted 
Pivoted's Type : Data Frame 
Pivoted's Size: (312,144)
The number of columns is different for each row of 'pivoted'.

pivoted.plot.hist(
    bins = 68,
    subplots=True,
    layout=(12, 12),
    figsize=(20 ,20),
    range = (-1000,1000),
    rwidth  = 1000,
    sharey=True)
```

[image]

How can I fit all the layouts?

Help me please.

Comment: What is the expected output? A graphical representation of the fits? A pandas dataframe of the fitted parameters of the Gaussian function? What have you tried, why did it fail?

Comment: I want a graph that combines the above graph and the fitted graph.

Additionally, can Gaussian fitted values be obtained according to bins size?

Comment: Seaborn's [histplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) can also generate kernel density estimate curves which, looking at your sample, should for your data be pretty close to Gaussian curves. If you really want pure Gaussian fits, you have to loop over the dataframe and fit each individually, I think.  And what does `can Gaussian fitted values be obtained according to bins size` mean? You fit on raw data, not on binned data.